# FactoryBot on heroku production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I'm trying to use gem FactoryBot at heroku..
On locally everything works fine, the factories are properly found.
I'm trying use factory outside spec folder.

I use it in service `invoice.rb`:

```
class InvoiceService
  @invoices ||= FactoryBot.build_list :invoice, 50, :with_invoice_positions
end
```

Here how it looks my invoice factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :invoice do
    ...

    trait :with_invoice_positions do
      transient do
        invoice_positions_count 5
      end

      after(:build) do |invoice, evaluator|
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Last thing is by Gemfile where I placed FactoryBot line outside the :test group:

```
ruby '2.5.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
...
gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.8.2'
gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', branch: 'master'
...

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  ...
end

group :development do
  ...
end

group :test do
  ...
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Error while trying to run rails server at heroku:

```
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816776+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816856+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: invoice (ArgumentError)
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816893+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816894+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot.rb:100:in `factory_by_name'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:12:in `run'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816898+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in define_list_strategy_method'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:32:in `times'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816906+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:32:in `each'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:32:in `map'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816910+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:32:in `block in define_list_strategy_method'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816912+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/services/invoice_service.rb:2:in `<class:InvoiceService>'
2018-03-16T13:13:16.816913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/services/invoice_service.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I anyone succeeded in use the factory bot on production mode?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why would you use factory bot in production?

Comment: It's really simple I combine it with faker and generate fake data on prod demonstratively, it also simulate getting data from third party API..

Comment: This is very intriguing, why would you need fake data in prod anyway? Shouldnt all those tests pass as part of TDD practice?

Comment: He may want to set up a demo instance for a client? @m1l05z you might want to investigate if seeds are not better for your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

factory_bot don't include itself everywhere by default only in specs where you would normally use it.

Try doing

```
require 'factory_bot'
FactoryBot.find_definitions
```

In the `invoice.rb`

If that works, you can add `factory_bot.rb` file in initializers with the same content to have it loaded when rails app starts (depending on your preferences)

Please see https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-without-bundler for more info.

Comment: Worked I also change in gemfile `gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.8.2', require: false` anyway thanks!